# Ajax Form Submit to Partial View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm rendering a form in a partial view and would also like the display the results there. Nothing is happening on form submit. I know the logic in the controller for querying the database is correct because it was working previously as a traditional HTML form.

Any suggestions?

Controller:

```
public ActionResult nameSearch(DashboardViewModel model)
        {

  //do some stuff here; I'm certain this part works

            return PartialView("_nameSearch", model);

        }
```

Partial View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("nameSearch", "Dashboard", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.name, new { })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.name, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>


}

                    <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="Submit">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <table>
                        @if (IsPost)
                        {
                            foreach (var u in Model.listschools)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;@u.instnm<br />@u.city, @u.state<br />@u.url
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                            }
                        }
                    </table>
```

Comment: Where and How are you using the partial view ?

Comment: The partial view is within a page that contains multiple tabs which will have a form on each tab. The partial view is part of the page /Dashboard/Index.

Comment: Couple of things here but first things first:  What shows up in the console?  Networks tab?  "Nothing is happening" is a bit vague.

Comment: You need to return a partial view result which has only the search result and in the Ajax.BeginForms call, use `UpdateTargetId` to update the UI with the response coming back.

Comment: The only thing showing up in the console is XHR finished loading: GET "<URL>".; I have no idea what this means.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the `Ajax.BeginForm` helper to add ajaxy behavior to your search, you should specify the `UpdateTargetId` so that the unobtrusive-ajax library knows which part of the page should be updated with the results coming back from the ajax call.

Also, you may want to return another partial view result, which has just the result items. You may create another partial view called `_SearchResults.chtml`.

Here i am simply using the timestamp and the search keyword. You may update it with your code which renders the tabular representation of data you want to display.

```
<h3>@ViewBag.Title</h3>
<p>Search happened at @DateTime.Now.ToString()</p>
```

Now in your action method, you will return partial view result of this new partial view.

```
public ActionResult Search(string term)
{
    ViewBag.Title = "Searching for : "+ term;
    // Replace the above with your actual code
    // which gets actual data and pass to the partial view
    return PartialView("_Search");
}
```

In the above example, I am simply passing a message via ViewBag. You may replace it by passing a list of items (generated by querying your database).

Now in your other view, specify the `UpdateTargetId` option when using the `Ajax.BeginForm` helper method.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Home", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", 
                                                      UpdateTargetId = "searchResults" }))
{
    <div class="row form-group">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="term" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
<div id="searchResults"> </div>
```

When the results comes back from server, the library will update the result(the html markup generated by partial view result) inside the div with Id `searchResults`

Comment: So if I want the search results to be formatted a certain way, do I need to build that HTML in the controller?

Comment: No. You will write the HTML in the view file.

Comment: Does that mean that the searchResults div, in the above example, will have a forEach loop that loops through the results and builds my table with them?

Comment: After implementing the above suggestion, the search results are returning properly but in a separate page? How do I keep them in the page the partial view is embedded into?

Comment: That means you do not have the needed js files loaded to the page (`jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` is the library you need for the ajaxy form behavior)

Comment: Here is the link https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/master/src/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js

Comment: Hm. So again, nothing is happening and the console shows nothing. I added a <div id = "searchResults"> and added the UpdateTargetID.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168765/discussion-between-shyju-and-sartorialist).