# ajax django form to submit just a partial of data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

EDIT: Changed the HTML form statement to work like so:

```
<form action="." class="form-horizontal" id="groupinfoForm" onsubmit="SubmitToServer()" method="post">
```

Question: Do i still also need the method="post">

Also changed the javascript to work with the onsubmit:

```
  function SubmitToServer() {

    event.preventDefault();

    //some ajaxy goodness here... still working on this.
     $.ajax({
        data: $("#groupinfoForm").serialize(),
        success: function(resp){
              alert ("resp: "+resp.name);
          }    
      })


    //I thinK i have to change all this to work inside the .ajax call?

    formData = $('form').serializeArray()
    $('#group_info option:first').prop('selected',true);

    gid = $('#group_info option:selected').val()
    //test alert
     alert("Submitting data for provider: " + $("#provider_id").val() + " and  " + gid + " and " + formData[0]['date_joined']);
    $("#groupinfo-dialog").modal('hide');
  }
```

I have a form, that is standard django.  Fill it out send it off goes to a different page upon success..shows errors if you don't fill out portions.

Now I have a modal form that will pop up to fill out some extra data.  I have decided to try to my hand at ajax for this.  I have some of it working:

Inside the class that is an UpdateView:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):  
    if self.request.POST.has_key('group_info_submit') and request.is_ajax():      
      print("YOU SURE DID SUBMIT")
      return HttpResponse("hi ya!")
```

The problem is it always redirects to a different page, and fails validation anyway because the form the modal pops over is not complete and trying to be submitted.

I saw this post here:

[Ajax Form Submit to Partial View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49781134/ajax-form-submit-to-partial-view)

This seems overly complicated, I just have a small div in my form that is a modal div that I would like to submit sort of separately from the rest...  The java script I have in the code:

```
  $.ajax({
    data: $("#groupinfoForm").serialize(),
    success: function(resp){
          alert ("resp: "+resp.name);
      }    
  })
```

Then the little modal html snippet is:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="groupinfo-dialog" class="modal" title="Group Information" style="display:none">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <h1> Group Information </h1>
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form action="." class="form-horizontal" id="groupinfoForm" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}            
            {{ group_information_form.non_field_errors }}
            <div class="col-md-12">
              {{ group_information_form.date_joined_group.errors }}
              {{ group_information_form.date_joined_group.label_tag }}
              {{ group_information_form.date_joined_group }}
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
              {{ group_information_form.provider_contact.errors }}
              {{ group_information_form.provider_contact.label_tag }}
              {{ group_information_form.provider_contact }}
            </div>
             <div class="col-md-12">
              {{ group_information_form.credentialing_contact.errors }}
              {{ group_information_form.credentialing_contact.label_tag }}
              {{ group_information_form.credentialing_contact }}
            </div>

              <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 form-actions">
                  <input type='button' class='btn' onclick="CancelDialog()" value='Cancel'/>
                  <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' onclick="SubmitToServer()" value='Save' name='group_info_submit'/>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                </div>
              </div>

            <input type="hidden" id="provider_id" name="provider_id" value="{{ provider_id }}" />
            <input type="hidden" id="group_id" name="group_id" value="{{ group_id }}" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- end modal Group Info Dialog -->
```

I do have a model form on the backend in the forms.py here. Also note there was a SubmitToServer() call, that is where I thought I could toss all the ajax stuff over the fence to the server, but I guess I need that $.ajax?   I am still learning the deeper parts of jquery.  I want to do a lot of preprocessing before i submit the data.  My attempt at the submittoserver javascript was here:

Wasn't sure how to get all the form data (just the three fields I care about from the modal) to send it over...my attempt here:

```
  function SubmitToServer() {
    formData = $('form').serializeArray()
    $('#group_info option:first').prop('selected',true);

    gid = $('#group_info option:selected').val()
   alert("Submitting data for provider: " + $("#provider_id").val() + " and  " + gid + " and " + formData[0]['date_joined']);
    $("#groupinfo-dialog").modal('hide');
  }
```

So can I bypass the main form validation and just send the three fields over somehow? and not have it redirect but stay on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to intercept the submit event. add onsubmit="someFunction()" to the form. In the someFunction ajax the data you want to validate before submitting, and if all is ok return true, else false.

https://jsfiddle.net/am5f14oc/

```
<html>
<body>
<form onsubmit="validateFunc()" action="." method="post">
<input id="name" type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the javascript

```
function validateFunc() {
    formData = $('form').serializeArray();
    // do ajax or whatever and return true if everything is ok
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: Ohhh okay, updated my code to reflect.  So much closer now.  So not sure how to grab that data on the server django side.   I  am guessing not in the def post?  It seems with this new intercept method the     if self.request.POST.has_key('group_info_submit') and request.is_ajax():  
inside the def post is not being called anymore...I am sure it is the 
     event.preventDefault();  but if I don't have that in there it tries to submit the whole form again and django catches the validation on the form

Comment: By intercepting the submit event form will not submit unless you return true from the intercepting function. Inside that function you can do wherever you want, ajax the data from the actual form to another form in django to validate, etc. I'm not familiar with Django but the principles are the same for the entire platform.

Comment: When you get the data from the form, just ajax to ANOTHER url/django script that validate the data, not to the same..

Comment: You rock Merak, I think I am on the right path, I did a django view url and just call that in the url: method from the .ajax call in javascript